# unable to convert Edittext to int

Tags: android, kotlin, android-edittext

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)

        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)

        var X: EditText = findViewById(R.id.num12)
        var Y: EditText = findViewById(R.id.num2)
        var B: Button = findViewById(R.id.btn1)
        var vir: TextView = findViewById(R.id.virw)

        var X1: Int = X.text.toString().toInt()
        var Y1: Int = Y.text.toString().toInt()
        B.setOnClickListener() {
            vir.text = "add new ${addtwonumber(X1, Y1)}"
        }
    }
    
    private fun addtwonumber(a:Int,b:Int):Int{
        return a+b
    }
}
```

> ```
> Error 2021-11-20 20:29:39.940 29733-29733/com.example.calibrate
> E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
>     Process: com.example.calibrate, PID: 29733
>     java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.calibrate/com.example.calibrate.MainActivity}:
> java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: ""
>         at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3528)
>         at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3703)
>         at android.app.servertransaction.LaunchActivityItem.execute(LaunchActivityItem.java:85)
>         at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeCallbacks(TransactionExecutor.java:135)
>         at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:95)
>         at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2152)
>         at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106)
>         at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:250)
>         at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7886)
>         at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
>         at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:592)
>         at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:970)
>      Caused by: java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: ""
>         at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:627)
>         at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:650)
>         at com.example.calibrate.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.kt:23)
>         at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:8108)
>         at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:8092)
>         at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1309)
>         at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3501)
>         at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3703) 
>         at android.app.servertransaction.LaunchActivityItem.execute(LaunchActivityItem.java:85) 
>         at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeCallbacks(TransactionExecutor.java:135) 
>         at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:95) 
>         at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2152) 
>         at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106) 
>         at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:250) 
>         at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7886) 
>         at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
>         at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:592) 
>         at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:970) 
> 2021-11-20 20:29:39.957 29733-29733/com.example.calibrate I/Process:
> Sending signal. PID: 29733 SIG: 9
> ```

Answer (score 2):

Looks at this line of the error:
`java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: ""`
You have an empty string (because your EditText is empty initially) which your are trying to convert to an `Int`. That's why you are getting the `NumberFormatException`.

You can fix the error by using `String.toIntOrNull()`. This function returns `null` instead of throwing an exception if the string cannot be converted to an `Int`. Then you can maybe use the elvis operator(`?:`) to use a default value for the `null` `Int`.

```kotlin
val X1: Int = X.text.toString().toIntOrNull() ?: 0 // Use zero if string does not represent an Int
```

On a side note, please use `val`s instead of `var`s for properties that are not going to change and also give better names to them (X, Y, X1, Y2 don't look good)

Answer (score 0):

At the beginning your EditTexts are empty, so the error is because it can't convert empty "" to integer, so you can check first if it is not empty or use `toIntOrNull()` function, but you also want to get the x and y when the user clicks on the button not at the beginning so the right way is to move your code from onCreate to onClickListener body

```
B.setOnClickListener() {
    val X1: Int = X.text.toString().toInt()
    val Y1: Int = Y.text.toString().toInt()
    vir.text = "add new ${addtwonumber(X1, Y1)}"
}
```